# Pandas collapse multiple columns starting with a character into row/columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have recently flatten deeply nested list of dictionary into a data frame:`[{},{{}},..,{}]`. I have more that 1500+ columns, I am trying to find a smart way to collapse these into rows and columns in a clean way. Here is my sample (easier), my real data is harder. I just wanted to kick start to see if there is a solution for it. I am unable solve just these two columns.

Column names are starting with a 1x,2x,...1500+x.
I only have 1 row.
Here is my DataFrame:

```
0_FileName  1_FileName  2_FileName  3_FileName  0_Year  1_Year  2_Year  3_Year
abc.pdf     def.txt     abc.ppt     def.pdf     2016    2016    2017    2018
```

I am trying to get an output like this one: Is it possible?

```
FileName,Year
abc.pdf,2016
def.txt,2016
abc.ppt,2017
def.pdf,2018
```

My Tries:

```
df.T # just does the transpose. thoughts of grouping it?
df['FileName'] = df['0_FileName'] + ',' + df['1_FileName'] .... # problem with this is that I have do this many many times. Then split it by ',', and explode it through pandas functionality.
```

Is there is function in pandas that it can solve these problems? Shape of my dataframe is (1500+ columns, 1 Row) because of flattening. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: do the columns follow a logical pattern? as in `fileName` and `Year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ide is create `MultiIndex` in columns by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` and then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last set default index values by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  FileName  Year
0  abc.pdf  2016
1  def.txt  2016
2  abc.ppt  2017
3  def.pdf  2018
```

Or use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with rename for numbers after `_`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1])).reset_index(), 
                      ['FileName','Year'],
                      i='index',
                      j='value', 
                      sep='_').reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
  FileName  Year
0  abc.pdf  2016
1  def.txt  2016
2  abc.ppt  2017
3  def.pdf  2018
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This a great start for me. I have much complicated flatten structured, I will give a try using similar techniques from your solution...lets see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way `melt`

```
s=df.melt()
s.join(s.variable.str.split('_',expand=True)).pivot(0,1,values='value')
1 FileName  Year
0               
0  abc.pdf  2016
1  def.txt  2016
2  abc.ppt  2017
3  def.pdf  2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need `reshape` if numbers of `FileName` and `Year` are equal:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(2,-1).transpose(), columns=['FileName','Year'])
```

Output:

```
  FileName  Year
0  abc.pdf  2016
1  def.txt  2016
2  abc.ppt  2017
3  def.pdf  2018
```